# Running UTF-8 Java file on Windows 10 same as on Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, encoding, utf-8

I have gradle project I created in linux OS. It contains some java files with standard UTF-8 encoding. One class contains string with central-europe characters.

Sometimes I use my second computer with Windows 10. When I want to run this gradle project correctly on win10 via CMD, I have to resave java files with ISO-8859-2 encoding and repair strings. It is very annoying and I didn't find way to run same with both systems.

I tried:
- JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS >> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in environmental variables
- CHCP 65001 (before start in CMD)
- UTF-8 in Windows locale setting (beta W10 feature)

Same bad results.

Is there any way?

Comment: Which editor or IDE do you use?

Comment: Regarding _"repair strings"_ and _"Same bad results"_, can you provide some code and some output demonstrating the problem? It's hard to propose a solution without more specific details.

Comment: Dear... guys. IDE neither sample code is not necessary. Right answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative would be to write any non-standard characters as Unicode escape sequences, e.g. `\u01D1`. This would make the file work anywhere with no local environment changes necessary. You also wouldn't have to worry about editing the file on the wrong environment and saving it with the wrong character set. But, of course, the foreign characters wouldn't be so easily legible in the file.

If your Gradle file contains foreign characters, set the environment variable `GRADLE_OPTS`:

```
GRADLE_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

If you are trying to *compile* the Java source files with Gradle, you may need to configure the encoding for the `compileJava` task, within the `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```